# Linking a local copy of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, http-status-code-404, bootstrap-4

So Im trying to link a local copy of bootstrap (It works with a CDN). I have bootstrap.css installed in the same directory as index.ejs and yet I keep getting these 404 errors.

So the file path for bootstrap.css is /home/daniel/scheduler/doc_display/app/bootstrap.css

and index is: /home/daniel/scheduler/doc_display/app/index.ejs

Any help would be much apreciated

Comment: Probably wrong path, try to copy the path to other tab in the browser and add or remove folder in the path until the file will load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the bootstrap.css file inside of my dist directory then included the new path inside the link tag. For some reason webpack seems to find paths when they are in the dist directory

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is going to look for the file relative to the location of the page it loads, so you need to make sure your path is correct.

Right now it's looking for it in the same folder as the index, which it looks like isn't where it's located.

Comment: So the file path for bootstrap.css is /home/daniel/scheduler/doc_display/app/bootstrap.css

Comment: and index is:  /home/daniel/scheduler/doc_display/app/index.ejs

Comment: they seem to be in the same directory I dont know what the problem is

Comment: Try `href="/home/daniel/scheduler/doc_display/app/bootstrap.css"` (absolute path)

Comment: You can also use `console.log(window.location.pathname);` within your script tag to log the current directory to the console, to make sure you are where you think you are. Electron can be disorienting in that regard.

Comment: Don't forget the href is relative to the http document root, not your filesystem root.  So `/home/...` might not be what you want.  Maybe `./bootstrap.css` or `../bootstrap.css`?  Also check file permissions (file needs to be readable by your web server process)